# Random Generator slightly less random

Tags: objective-c

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"category == %@", selectedCategory];
NSArray *filteredArray = [self.Quotes filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
// Get total number in filtered array
int array_tot = (int)[filteredArray count];
// As a safeguard only get quote when the array has rows in it
if (array_tot > 0) {
    // Get random index
    int index = (arc4random() % array_tot);
    // Get the quote string for the index
    NSString *quote = [[filteredArray objectAtIndex:index] valueForKey:@"quote"];
    // Display quote
    self.quote_text.text = quote;
    // Update row to indicate that it has been displayed
    int quote_array_tot = (int)[self.Quotes count];
    NSString *quote1 = [[filteredArray objectAtIndex:index] valueForKey:@"quote"];
    for (int x=0; x < quote_array_tot; x++) {
        NSString *quote2 = [[Quotes objectAtIndex:x] valueForKey:@"quote"];
        if ([quote1 isEqualToString:quote2]) {
            NSMutableDictionary *itemAtIndex = (NSMutableDictionary *)[Quotes objectAtIndex:x];
            [itemAtIndex setValue:@"DONE" forKey:@"source"];
        }
    }
```

Above is the code I use in my app for generating a random quote from one of two categories stored in a plist (in arrays, where the first line is category, and second is quote). However, it seems to have a preference of repeating ones it's already shown. I'd prefer it have a preference (but not exclusively) show ones it *hasn't* shown before.

Comment: You should use `arc4random_uniform` to avoid modulo bias and see if this helps.  If you still want to change the output then you will need to do it yourself; keep a track of unseen vs seen quotes, randomly decide if you will show a seen or unseen (biased towards unseen) and then randomly select one the quotes

Comment: @Paulw11 so correct me if I'm wrong, but replacing (arc4random() % array_tot) with (arc4random_uniform(array_tot)) will give a truly random quote? if so, that's good enough for me.

Comment: @Paulw11: do you think any user of the app will ever notice the modulo bias? I mean, the OP is obviously not coding an online poker platform.

Comment: @Michael maybe it's placebo, but I seem to notice it repeating the same quotes than it did more often than it showing new ones

Comment: @Branch: arc4random() is fine, no need to change it in this case. There is such a thing as modulo bias, but it will not be a problem for your application. - You don't want a truly random quote. You want a low-discrepancy sequence. An LDS looks more random, but in fact it is less random

Comment: You can log the random index that you get and look at that (`NSLog(@"generated random index: %d", index);`), maybe the problem is somewhere else, and you generate random numbers less often than you thought.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is an algorithm question. What you want is a sequence of numbers that seems random but is more uniform.

What you are looking for is called a [low-discrepancy sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-discrepancy_sequence). A simple form of this is a "shuffle bag", often used in game development, as described [here](https://seanmonstar.com/post/708989796/a-less-random-generator) or [here](https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/shuffle-bags-making-random-feel-more-random--gamedev-1249).

With a shuffle bag, you basically generate all the indices (e.g. 0 1 2 3 4 5), shuffle them (e.g. 2 3 5 1 0 4) and then display the elements in this order. At the end, you generate another sequence (e.g. 4 1 0 2 3 5). Note that it is possible that the same element appears twice in the sequence, although it is rare. E.g. in this case, the "4" is a duplicate, because the full sequence is 2 3 5 1 0 **4 4** 1 0 2 3 5.

`arc4random()` is a good PRNG on Apple platforms, so it doesn't give you a "low discrepancy sequence". But: you can use it as a primitive to generate "low discrepancy sequences", you can also use it as a primitive to create a shuffle bag implementation.

Comment: This means all quotes are shown before repeats? How would I modify arc4random to get this?

Comment: @Branch: you cannot. The problem is more complicated than this. You have to create your own random-number-generation-object. The details are described in the links I provided.

Comment: gotcha. You are correct about the LDS-- It's random, but because I'm a human, I "expect" random to be evenly distributed. Nonetheless, the uniform seems to help a little, so I'll keep that. Thanks for your help and quick replies.

Comment: something I just thought of... is there a way with arc4random to at least ensure the same quote isn't shown twice in a row? I do have some code that looks like it could be modified to help (see: // Update row to indicate that it has been displayed) in OP. Thanks.

Comment: @Branch: well, do you know which item you showed last? (If not, just save the index into some variable.) If so, repeat the random number generation until you get a different value.

Comment: I can set the variable, where I get lost is how to repeat the generation until the value is new. For example, if I say, save the index to a variable called index, I can't tell it to repeat until index doesn't equal index. I really do appreciate all your help so far and quick replies.